# A varying number of Fragments for FragmentPagerAdapter based on attributes or object passed to it?

Tags: java, android

Using a `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    //declating number of items statically
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 5;

    private MyObject myobject;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        //getting object as a public static from activity
        myobject = MyActivity.object_holder;
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return ContentFragment.newInstance(myobject.getOverview(), "Overview");
            case 1: return ContentFragment.newInstance(myobject.getGetting_around(), "Getting Around");
            case 2: return ContentFragment.newInstance(myobject.getShopping(), "Shopping");
            case 3: return ContentFragment.newInstance(myobject.getNightlife(), "Nightlife");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0: return "Overview";
            case 1: return "Getting Around";
            case 2: return "Shopping";
            case 3: return "Nightlife";
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that if the `myobject` object has an empty field, for example `Shopping` or `NightLife`. ie. it equals `null`.

Then I don't want to show the whole pager item.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, for starters, you'll want to get rid of the hardcoded item count. In stead, make it dynamic by checking for the fields that may or may not be empty. You can do this using a simple loop. If the fields never change during the lifetime of the pager, then you only have to do this once and you can cache the value.